# useEffect hook to check if browser is opened in mobile so that logo is displayed accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, docusaurus

This code is of the component which displays website logo accordingly. But problem with this code is,
I am getting "ReferenceError: window is not defined"
Because in SSR, its unable to catch 'window' in my following code.

```
import React from "react";

export default function NavbarLogo(props) {
const isMobileScreen = window?.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")?.matches;

return (
    <img
        className="navbar__brand navbar__logo"
        src={
            isScreen
                ? "imagelink1.png"
                : "imagelink2.png"
        }
    />
  );
}
```

I am thinking of using a UseEffect and passing a isBrowser as a prop then passing my isMobileScreen query.
But i'm unable to figure out how to refactor this component.
Can someone please help me out with the code?

Comment: why don't you do that purely via CSS?

Comment: you can check with `navigator.userAgent` to see which browser and which device has the app open

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using CSS to do this? For example:

```
.navbar__logo {
  /* Default logo */
  background-image: url("imagelink1.png");
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .navbar__logo {
    /* Logo for larger screens */
    background-image: url("imagelink2.png");
  }
}
```

This will display the default logo on screens with a width of 768px or less, and display the alternate logo on screens with a width of 769px or more.

You can also use the max-width media query to specify a maximum screen width instead of a minimum screen width. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar__logo {
    /* Logo for smaller screens */
    background-image: url("imagelink1.png");
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .navbar__logo {
    /* Logo for larger screens */
    background-image: url("imagelink2.png");
  }
}
```

This will display the alternate logo on screens with a width of 768px or less, and display the default logo on screens with a width of 769px or more.